# "Missing return statement" error occurring despite its presence

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement an exception checker but some reason an error occurs. I don't know why I'm getting this error when the return statement is clearly there. Does anyone what needs to be done in order to fix this?

**Error**

> Missing return statement

**Code**

```
    private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                // Set text
                textView.setText(values[position]);
                // Set color depending on position
                int textColorId = R.color.white; // Default color
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        textColorId = R.color.brown; break;
                    case 1:
                        textColorId = R.color.red; break;
                    case 2:
                        textColorId = R.color.yellow; break;
                }
                textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
                return rowView;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

```
private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            // Set text
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            // Set color depending on position
            int textColorId = R.color.white; // Default color
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    textColorId = R.color.red;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textColorId = R.color.yellow;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textColorId = R.color.green;
                    break;
            }
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if `convertView != null`?

Comment: Indent your code properly and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: wow, this is basic coding question, every single line of execution needs to have return statement. Like Reimeus stated what happens when converView is not null

Comment: My return statement IS there i.e. `return rowView;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
return rowView;
        }
```

To this:

```
    }
return rowView;
```

Your return is inside the if =) It's hard to tell because you didn't indent correctly.

Make sure to add:

```
View rowView = null;
```

before the if statement or you will be out of scope.

Comment: This is going to produce unwanted effects, because once he has convertView != null his rowView is always going to be null, and therefore return null. Edit your answer.

Comment: I agree. Just got the warning **Value 'rowView' is always 'null'**

Comment: Just add View rowView = convertView; instead of null

Comment: @MarkoLazić Gotten lost a bit, please check my **Update** code

Comment: wait you corrected your code, now the return statement error is gone. What seems to be the problem now?

Comment: @MarkoLazić Based on the update, it says that 'rowView' is already defined

Comment: remove double initialization, 
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
into this
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
These are basic questions, why are you struggling with this.